# How do I make a field required based on multiple conditions in JSON Schema?

Tags: jsonschema

How can I make a property required based on the value of 2 (or more) other properties?

For instance,

```
{
  "properties": {
    "property1": {
      "type": "string"
      },
    "property2": {
      "type": "string"
      }
    "property3":{
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I make property3 required based on the values of property1 and property2?

It **seems** like I need to use `allOf`, but

```
"allOf": [
    {
    "if": {
        ...
    },
    "then": {
        ...
    }},
    "if": {
        ...
    },
    "then": {
        ...
    }
]
```

has multiple `then` blocks when what I really need is multiple conditions for only one `then` block.

Comment: You could put the `allOf` inside the `if` condition.

Comment: Thanks @Ether -- it worked for me. Did not realize you could invert allOf and if but it makes sense. Cheers.